# Can't Load Module Using Configuraton File

Tags: wpf, prism

I am trying to load a module using a configuration file but keep getting the following exception.

```
An exception occurred while initializing module 'HelloWorld'. 
- The exception message was: The method or operation is not implemented.
- The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:HelloWorld, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception
occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() 
to help locate the root cause of the problem.
```

I have the following App.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism"/>
  </configSections>

  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="HelloWorld.dll" moduleType="HelloWorld.HelloWorldModule, HelloWorld, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="HelloWorld" startupLoaded="true" />
  </modules>
</configuration>
```

I have double checked the dll name, namespace and type name and I even recreate the project from scratch but the error still shows up. Please help me on this problem as I am stuck for several hours already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. It seems this error shows up when the Initialize() method of your module is not yet implemented.

```
public class HelloWorldModule : IModule
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But that is still wiered as the debugger should throw the error the NotImplementedException and not other else.